# Copy XML node with added changes to child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I have one specific problem. I have XML which i would need transformed so one node gets copied.

Input XML is:

```
<root>
    <book>
        <name>
        ... some data
        </name>
        <info>
        ... some data
        </info>
        <trees>
            <tag1></tag1>
            <tag2></tag2>
            <tag3></tag3>
            .... other tags
            <tag n+1></tag n+1> 
        </trees>
        .
        .
        .
        other nodes
        .
        .
        .
        .
        </book>
        <book>
        .
        .
        .
        </book>
</root>
```

Now i would need to copy node "trees" 3 times and write it like this with little changes to sub nodes. Output XML would need to be like:

```
<root>
    <book>
        <name>
        ... some data
        </name>
        <info>
        ... some data
        </info>

        <trees>
            <tag1></tag1>
            <tag2></tag2>
            <tag3></tag3>
            .... other tags
            <tag n+1></tag n+1> 
        </trees>
        <treesA>
            <tag1A></tag1A>
            <tag2A></tag2A>
            <tag3A></tag3A>
            .... other tags
            <tag n+1></tag n+1> 
        </treesA>
        <treesA>
            <tag1B></tag1B>
            <tag2B></tag2B>
            <tag3B></tag3B>
            .... other tags
            <tag n+1></tag n+1> 
        </treesB>
        <treesC>
            <tag1C></tag1C>
            <tag2C></tag2C>
            <tag3C></tag3C>


    .... other tags
        <tag n+1></tag n+1> 
    </treesC>
    .
    .
    .
    other nodes
    .
    .
    .
    .
</book>
<book>
.
.
.
</book>
```

Thanks for all your help regarding my problem. Eoglasi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite nicely in XSLT 2.0 using a tunnel parameter to hold the suffix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="''" />
    <xsl:element name="{name()}{$suffix}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trees">
    <xsl:next-match />
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="'A'" />
    </xsl:next-match>
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="'B'" />
    </xsl:next-match>
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="suffix" tunnel="yes" select="'C'" />
    </xsl:next-match>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect 10 answer, thanks. Can you also advise if this transformation leaves every thing else in XML the same as it was before?

Comment: @eoglasi pretty much, the only thing that might change is if you have a namespace declared on a parent element but only used by its descendants (in which case the declaration will move down the tree to the point where it is being used).  Your example XML doesn't include any namespaces so this shouldn't be an issue in your case but if it is you can try adding `<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />` directly after the opening `<xsl:element>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and help regarding this matter. Eoglasi

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="trees">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="change">
    <xsl:with-param name="suffix" select="'A'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="change">
    <xsl:with-param name="suffix" select="'B'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="change">
    <xsl:with-param name="suffix" select="'C'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="change">
  <xsl:param name="suffix"/>
  <xsl:element name="{name()}{$suffix}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="change">
      <xsl:with-param name="suffix" select="$suffix"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```